# How to clean up after a Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO) 2010 Outlook Add-In completes

Tags: c#, outlook, garbage-collection, vsto

Microsoft has a Walkthrough for a simple VSTO 2010 Outlook Add-In that perfectly illustrates a problem I am seeing in a more complex Add-In that I support.  Here is a link to the Walkthrough:

[FirstOutlookAddin Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx)

and here is the code from the walkthrough that I have copied into a C# VSTO 2010 Outlook Add-In project:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace FirstOutlookAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
            new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
                   .InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
            {
                mailItem.Subject = "Added Text";
                mailItem.Body = "Added Text to Body";
            }
        }
    }

    #region VSTO generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }      
    #endregion
}
}
```

The problem that I have is in using this code in combination with Entrust to send an encrypted email, and then recalling the email message and re-sending it after edit.  Once I re-send it (after the recall and edit) it corrupts the message, and when I try to open it I get the following error:

> Sorry, we're having trouble opening this item.  this could be
>   temporary, but if you see it again you might want to restart Outlook. 
>   An error occurred in the underlying security system. An internal error
>   occurred.

I'm almost certain that the problem with this is that one or more of the objects being used locally isn't getting cleaned up automatically by the Garbage Collector, but I'm not sure how to force the Garbage Collector (GC) to clean this up so it will work properly.  I've been trying to set the local objects to null, and have found some posts that discuss calling:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

And have been trying that too, but have had no luck so far.  Can anyone provide some pointers on how to fix this problem?

Comment: May be you have to unsubscribe from your event subscriptions? Have a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omars/archive/2004/12/07/276136.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the GC twice if you want to get unused COM objects swiped from the heap. For example:

```
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

But the better way is to use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.